# Clone a directed graph - Leetcode question

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm having some trouble understanding the bug in my code and why it's timing out.
The problem is to create a clone of a directed graph.
Here's a link to the question: https://www.educative.io/m/clone-directed-graph

My solution uses a queue twice. The first time I map all the nodes in the graph to what its corresponding node in the clone would be.

The second time I use to queue to iterate over the neighbours but get their corresponding mapped values and add those to the neighbours list for the current node I'm on.

Here's my code.

```
class Node {
  public int data;
  public List<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();
  public Node(int d) {data = d;}
}

class graph {
  public static Node clone(Node root) {
    //use a queue to search the graph
    //use a haspmap to map graph node to clone node
    
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    Map<Node, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    q.add(root);
    map.put(root, new Node(root.data));

    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
      Node current = q.remove();
      
      for(Node temp : current.neighbors) {
        Node cloneTemp = new Node(temp.data);
        if(!map.containsKey(temp)) {
          q.add(temp);
          map.put(temp, cloneTemp);
        }
      }
    }
    q.add(root);
    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
      Node current = q.remove();
      Node currentClone = map.get(current);
        for(Node temp : current.neighbors) {
          Node mapNode = map.get(temp)
          if(!currentClone.neighbors.contains(mapNode)) {
            currentClone.neighbors.add(mapNode);
            q.add(temp);
          }
        }
      }
      
    return map.get(root);
  }
}
```

Comment: What will happens in second `while` if you will have cycle in graph? Like node A pointing to node B and B pointing to A? You need to know which nodes was already visited and do not process them again.

Comment: @tym32167 that's right, thanks. I added that logic with an if statement it seems to be working now!